# Is http call significantly slower than local call generally and particularly in Flask?

Tags: python, rest, flask

I have a python library and need to provide services for others to use. Since the local installation is not a simple 'pip install ...' to complete, I want to set up a http service in Flask so users don't need to locally install it.

If the http server is very close to users' machines, I have a couple of questions to ask, since I am new to http service:

1. Is http call significantly slower than local call?
2. In local calls, my api can process texts (large amount of plaint text) in batches to speed up, instead of one by one processing. But the typical http service receives one text, process it and return it. Is that would be slower? Or the http client needs to write concurrent code to make http calls and the http service doesn't need to worry about any concurrency issue.
3. Is there any general method to speed up http service call?

My http service code would look like:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
api = Flask(__name__)
@api.route('/process', methods=['GET'])
def process():
    text, stopwords = _parse_parameters()
    pos = str(wlu.process(text, stopwords=stopwords))
    return pos

def _parse_parameters():
    
    text = request.args.get('text')
    stopwords = request.args.get('stopwords')

    return (text, stopwords)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #api.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='5000')
    from waitress import serve
    serve(api, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

EDIT:
'Local call' means users install the python library locally and do the typical importing of dependencies:

```
import my_library
```

Comment: What do you mean by "local call"? Do you mean `import foo` and then `foo()` directly in python code?

Comment: "Since the local installation is not a simple 'pip install ...' to complete" If you were to make this a Python package what else will the user need to do in addition to `pip install`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, yes, I mean users install my library locally and import dependencies in their code.